# How do I run a Node.js application on my local machine and using No-IP to let someone else access it from the Internet?

Tags: node.js, noip

My application defines a few callbacks (URLs), and I need to test them.

Is it possible to run a application on a local machine and let someone else access it from the Internet?

(I can't deploy my application to [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku), because it takes up to 30 minutes and this is not the best option when one needs to debug, fix possible bugs, and redeploy the application many times.)

So I want to use [No-IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-IP) to have some general IP address and give anyone access to my service that will run on my local machine.

1. Is it possible?
2. If possible - how to do it?

Comment: noip is viable but you may be interested in ngrok or similar services

Comment: @EricWong i use this - and its work perfect - but i want to know if it possible to use noip also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is using an HTTP server, you can use https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel to expose your API.

Even if you are not using an HTTP server in your application, you can simply create one and have some routes call your functions.

Comment: run your node js http server in a port, say 8000
run the command `lt --port 8000`
you will get a url. use the url to call your routes.